# Don't import row if it already exists in database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to import items from my CSV file to MSSQL database with Laravel 5.7. In my CSV file the first column is item_ids and second column is description.
How to now set to not download that items which ids are already in database?
ItemController:

```
public function import(Item $item, Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('itemsfile')) {
            if ($request->itemsfile->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'csv')
            {
                $rowCount = 0;
                $csvAsArray = array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, ";");}, file($request->file('itemsfile')));
                foreach($csvAsArray as $row)
                {
                    if(count($row)>=2){
                        if(trim($row[0]) != '' && trim($row[1]) != '') {
                            $item= new Item();
                            $item->item_id= $row[0];
                            $item->description= $row[1];
                            $item->save();
                            $rowCount++;
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                return redirect()->route('admin.items');
            }
            else {
                return back();
            }
        }
        else {
            return back();
        }
    }
```

ItemRequest:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'item_id' => 'required|unique:items'
        ];
    }
```

When I'm adding a new item (not importing it) unique id number checking works fine, but when I want to import packs from CSV file and don't import rows which are already in database the whole CSV is beeing imported.
Thank you for help!
dd(csvAsArray);

> array:30 [▼   0 => array:2 [▼
>       0 => "Desc 1"
>       1 => "123456789"   ]   1 => array:2 [▶] . . . etc.

Comment: can you print dd($csvAsArray) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if that data is already on the database:

```
if(Item::where('item_id','=',$row[0])->count() == 0) {
    $item= new Item();
    $item->item_id= $row[0];
    $item->description= $row[1];
    $item->save();
    $rowCount++;
}
```

Also, if you have an unique rule, you should do the same in your migrations file.
You may have something like this:

```
Schema::create('Item', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('item_id');
});
```

Then create a new migration with the unique rule

```
Schema::table('Item', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unique('item_id'); //add unique rule
});
```